# Is it possible to disable the "alt" key as it is used for default windows things, but still have it functional as a modifier key inside a program?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Using Pro Tools on a PC - the "alt" key is used as a modifier key but if you hit it once it will also bring you up into the file menu etc. Is there a way to make it only function as a modifier key?

Windows 7 by the way.

Comment: Just curious as to why?

Comment: It's easier to work without it bringing you up to the menu all the time.

Comment: If the `Alt` key is used as a modifier then that itself would usually prevent the default (menu) action from triggering? (Since the menu only gets focus on the _release_ of the `Alt` key.) However, if there is a conflict then I'm not sure how you can disable one and not the other - after all, there is only one `Alt` key. I did just wonder if it was possible to disable menu shortcuts. But even without any menu shortcuts, a user can still hit the `Alt` key and use the cursor keys to step through the menu.

Comment: If you want to disable this for the Explore then you can just write an autohotkey script for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t. There needs to be a keyboard-only way to access the menu.